# how can i install and configure asp.net with vs code in ubuntu?

Tags: asp.net, ubuntu, visual-studio-code

i was installing asp.net in my ubuntu system , the following command was not executed because "bower" was outdated

$ npm install -g yo bower grunt-cli gulp generator-aspnet

npm WARN deprecated bower@1.8.8: We don't recommend using Bower for new projects. Please consider Yarn and Webpack or Parcel. You can read how to migrate legacy project here: https://bower.io/blog/2017/how-to-migrate-away-from-bower/

npm WARN deprecated generator-aspnet@0.3.3: Use dotnet new instead
npm WARN deprecated gulp-util@3.0.8: gulp-util is deprecated - replace it, following the guidelines at https://medium.com/gulpjs/gulp-util-ca3b1f9f9ac5

npm WARN deprecated minimatch@2.0.10: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue

npm WARN deprecated samsam@1.1.2: This package has been deprecated in favour of @sinonjs/samsam

npm WARN deprecated formatio@1.1.1: This package is unmaintained. Use @sinonjs/formatio instead

npm WARN deprecated cross-spawn-async@2.2.5: cross-spawn no longer requires a build toolchain, use it instead

so how can i replace bower and grunt with alternatives ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use Yeoman to create asp .net project. In warning you have information what to do: `npm WARN deprecated generator-aspnet@0.3.3: Use dotnet new instead npm WARN` Just use [dotnet CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-new?tabs=netcore22). You can create empty asp .net project just using `dotnet new web` in your shell and that's all.